# Using HTML.EditorFor Vs using HTML.CheckBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, editorfor

I have the following model class which contains a bool value:-

```
Public class Server
{
        public bool IsIPUnique { get; set; }
}
```

Currently i am using the following to display the check box inside my Razor view:-

```
<input type="CheckBox" name="IsIPUnique" value="true" @(Html.Raw(Model.IsIPUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))/> IP Unique.
```

but i read about the EditorFor template, and it can automatically create the check box and check/uncheck it based on the model values so i tried the following  :-

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.IsIPUnique)<span>test</span>
```

so my question is if i can replace my old code with the new one that uses the EditorFor ?, or asp.net mvc might deal with these values differently ?
Thanks

Comment: So what happened when you tried the new code?

Comment: basically it generates the same HTML markup , but i am not sure about using the EditorFor instead of checkbox ?

Comment: Have you considered using Html.CheckBoxFor?

Comment: EditorFor is great when you don't care what kinds of inputs mvc generates for your model (meaning no editor templatE) OR when you want specific control over how your model (or part of your model) is generated. For the most part however you fill find the html helper methods like CheckBoxFor will do the trick for you.

Comment: Also, the main thing to keep in mind when using your forms is that you must set the name property for proper model binding and validation and such. MVC takes care of this for you when you use the html helper methods.

Comment: @MikeCheel so you mean it is better to use CheckBoxFor instead of EditorFor ?

Comment: What I am saying is that if all you need is a checkbox to be generated then CheckBoxFor is probably a good fit for you. If you need to have the chkbox rendered some different way for some reason you have that power too but it sounds like CheckBoxFor will work for you. If you need to add addl html attrs there is  an overload that allows you to do that. An example where you might not want to use CheckBoxFor is say you were using a custom control from some third party library that has some kind of special syntax or whatever (contrived I know). Most 3rd party librs these days wrap form inputs so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you have 3 possibilities:

**Write HTML manually (as you have done)**

I would avoid writing the HTML manually if there is a HTML helper available.
Manually written HTML is prone to errors which can cause problems with model binding.

**Use the specific HTML helpers (Html.CheckBoxFor)**

The specific HTML helpers add a layer of abstraction to all controls.
It's easy to modify the template of all controls that use the same HTML helper and it makes your views more readable.

**Use the general EditorFor**

The EditorFor HTML helper is great if your model datatypes change often.
The EditorFor will adjust the input fields automatically to the new datatype and won't throw an error (as with the specific HTML helpers).
It is also a bit harder to add HTML attributes to the EditorFor while the specific HTML helpers often have overloads for them.
However, this is fixed in MVC 5.1: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-3-bootstrap-and-javascript-enhancements

**Conclusion**: in your case I would use the CheckBoxFor HTML helper because the datatype won't change likely and it will make the view cleaner